# problem with Update in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

According to the documentation, joins, when used with the update statement, work in the same way as when used in selects.

For example, if we have these two tables:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM orders;
+---------+------------+
| orderid | customerid |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |          1 |
|       2 |          2 |
|       3 |          3 |
|       4 |          1 |
+---------+------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM customers;
+------------+------------+
| customerid | ordercount |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          9 |
|          2 |          3 |
|          3 |          8 |
|          4 |          5 |
|          5 |          7 |
+------------+------------+
```

using this select statements:

```
SELECT orders.customerid 
FROM orders 
JOIN customers ON (customers.customerid = orders.customerid)
```

returns:

```
+------------+
| customerid |
+------------+
|          1 |
|          1 |
|          2 |
|          3 |
+------------+
```

So, I was expecting the statement below:

```
UPDATE orders 
JOIN customers ON (customers.customerid = orders.customerid) 
SET ordercount = ordercount + 1
```

to update ordercount for customer #1 (customerid = 1) to be 11, but actually this is not the case, here are the results after the update:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM customers;
+------------+------------+
| customerid | ordercount |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |         10 |
|          2 |          4 |
|          3 |          9 |
|          4 |          5 |
|          5 |          7 |
+------------+------------+
```

As you can see it was only incremented once despite that it occurs twice in the orders table and despite that the select statement returns it correctly.

Is this a bug in MySQL or is it me doing something wrong? I'm trying to avoid using group by for performance reasons hence my interest to understand what's going on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be that this problem indirectly shows a flaw in your db design? maybe it's too much trouble keeping an ordercount. it can lead ot inconsistencies if you adjust such scores by indipendent updates. maybe it would be better to generate that count with a query, when you need it.

Comment: I only used the customers and orders example to demonstrate the problem, I'm not going to use it in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `MySQL` updates each record in a joined table at most once.

I cannot find it in the documentation, but practice says so.

I'll probably post it as a bug, so they at least add it to documentation:

```
CREATE TABLE updater (value INT NOT NULL);

INSERT
INTO    updater
VALUES  (1);

SELECT  *
FROM    updater;

value
---
1

UPDATE  updater u
JOIN    (
        SELECT  1 AS newval
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2
        ) q
SET     u.value = u.value + newval;

SELECT  *
FROM    updater;

value
---
2

(expected 4).
```

`SQL Server`, by the way, behaves same in a multiple table `UPDATE`.

You can use:

```
UPDATE  orders o
SET     ordercount = ordercount +
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    customers c
        WHERE   c.customerid = o.customerid
        )
```

which is same on performance as long as you have an index on `customers (customer_id)`

Comment: So, is this by design? The documentation doesn't say anything about this

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this in the question but actually I have more criteria in the join statement which I removed for the sake of making things simpler .. this code in your answer will update the whole table which is not what I want, customers can have a large number of records (it's not a customers table by the way, that was only used for demonstrating the problem), the join results only a few records to be updated

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer .. actually I only use a few records in orders (using some criteria) to update the customers table .. seems like using GROUP BY is the only way